# What is the default confidence interval used to draw error bars in a Seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Seaborn's barplot shows error bars or caps to "provide some indication of the uncertainty around that estimate." By default, what confidence interval is used to draw those error bars?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`seaborn v0.12.0`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.12.0.html#more-flexible-errorbars) the parameter is now `errorbar`.

See [Statistical estimation and error bars](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/error_bars.html).

> `errorbar` : `string`, (string, number) tuple, callable or `None`
> Name of errorbar method (either `'ci'`, `'pi'`, `'se'`, or `'sd'`), or a tuple with a method name and a level parameter, or a function that maps from a vector to a (min, max) interval, or `None` to hide errorbar.

The default is `errorbar=('ci', 95)`

---

According to the [documentation for version 0.8.1](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html#seaborn.barplot), the default value for the `ci` parameter of `seaboard.barplot` is `95`. So, by default, a Seaborn barplot is drawn with 95% confidence intervals.

The documentation given in the link above also states the accepted values for the `ci` parameter:

> `ci` : float or `"sd"` or `None`, optional
>
> Size of confidence intervals to draw around estimated values. If `"sd"`, skip bootstrapping and draw the standard deviation of the observations. If `None`, no bootstrapping will be performed, and error bars will not be drawn.

---

For the sake of completeness, here is the signature of the `seaboard.barplot` function according to the documentation linked at the top of this answer. `ci` is the parameter of interest.

> ```
> seaborn.barplot(
>   x=None,
>   y=None,
>   hue=None,
>   data=None,
>   order=None,
>   hue_order=None,
>   estimator=<function mean>,
>   ci=95,
>   n_boot=1000,
>   units=None,
>   orient=None,
>   color=None,
>   palette=None,
>   saturation=0.75,
>   errcolor='.26',
>   errwidth=None,
>   capsize=None,
>   dodge=True,
>   ax=None,
>   **kwargs
> )
> ```