# What are the vertical lines in seaborn plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

What are these vertical lines in Seaborn?

[image]

As I look up in the documentation, it seems that it is a confidence interval.

Just by looking, it's hard to pinpoint where those edges exactly lie in the y-axis.

**QUESTION**: Is there a way to show the values for those vertical lines (in red circle)?

Comment: [see this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576666/what-is-the-default-confidence-interval-used-to-draw-error-bars-in-a-seaborn-bar#50577142)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `capsize=...` will add a little cap to the confidence interval.
You can loop through the generated vertical lines and add some text based on their coordinates.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
ax = sns.barplot(x='day', y='tip', hue='smoker', palette='autumn', data=tips, capsize=.2)
sns.despine()
for line in ax.lines:
    xs, ys = line.get_data()
    if xs[0] == xs[1]:  # vertical line
        ax.text(xs[0], ys[0], f'\n\n{ys[0]:.1f}', ha='center', va='center', color='blue', size=14)
        ax.text(xs[1], ys[1], f'{ys[1]:.1f}\n\n', ha='center', va='center', color='blue', size=14)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with location of confidence interval]